# Is there a way to define a macro that turns a expression i.e. an int, into an String literal?

Tags: c, macros

Is there a way to put a define like this:

```
#define PUTVAL 0x00

#define foo(x) ("x")

int main()
{
    char *szFoo = foo(PUTVAL);

    return 0;
}
```

and get it modified by a macro, that szFoo would point to a stringliteral containing "0x00"
isntead of "x" ?

Comment: Why don't you set `szFoo` equal to `PUTVAL`? Put some quotes around `0x00`.

Comment: @staticx I don't get what you mean, sry.

Comment: I don't get it, do you want `szFoo` to be equal to `"PUTVAL"` or to be equal to `"0"` ?

Comment: @staticx Well ofc, it would work for this example, but I'm asking for a macro that fits my needs, not a workarround.

Comment: I want to get a stringliteral, containing what ever is handed over to the macro put between `"` so I could do `printf (foo(sdgsfdgfdgd))`and the output would simply be `sdgsfdgfdgd`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you have to use two levels of macro and it is called *stringification*:

http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Stringification.html

```
 #define xstr(s) str(s)
 #define str(s) #s
 #define foo 4
 str (foo)
      ==> "foo"
 xstr (foo)
      ==> xstr (4)
      ==> str (4)
      ==> "4"
```

Comment: Please edit a minimal version of the answer into the actual answer, just linking is not very good form.

Comment: That looks to me like a compiler extension, isn't it?

Comment: crazy :D but would be awesome anyway if you could add a minimal example

Comment: @Zaibis it isn't `#` has been around forever (seems that way anyway). the double layer of macros it to force the expansion of the initial input expression *before* applying the stringizer preprocessor operation (which happens in the second macro).

Comment: Stringification was added in c89/c90 IIRC.

Comment: Got a moment to get it. But this is realy nice, thanks.